# foreach loop isn't continuing once an `IF/ELSEIF` statement is true

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

This `foreach` loop doesn't seem to be progressing past the first `IF` statement that is true, even though every statement in this snippet is true. How can I modify the code so that it will continue looping through the array and statements?

```
    $Silhouettes = array('Skirt_Style-Pencil','Skirt_Style-Straight','Skirt_Style-A-Line','Skirt_Style-Full','Pant_Style-Straight'); 
    $Skirt_Style=array();
    $Pant_Style=array();

    foreach($Silhouettes as $key => $value ){
        if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Pencil', $Silhouettes)) {
           $Skirt_Style = 'Pencil';
        }elseif (in_array('Skirt_Style-Straight', $Silhouettes)) {
           $Skirt_Style = 'Straight';
        }elseif (in_array('Skirt_Style-A-Line', $Silhouettes)) {
           $Skirt_Style = 'A-Line';
        }elseif (in_array('Skirt_Style-Full', $Silhouettes)) {
           $Skirt_Style = 'Full';
        }elseif (in_array('Pant_Style-Straight', $Silhouettes)) {
           $Pant_Style = 'Straight';
        }
    }
 var_dump($Skirt_Style);
```

**Result is:**

```
string(6) "Pencil"
```

Comment: if you do not use the $key and $value, what is the sense in using a foreach?

Comment: Are you trying to save all of the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This right here is always true `if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Pencil', $Silhouettes))` so your loop will never reach any of the `else` cases.

Furthermore you overwrite your `$Skirt_Style` array in every loop with a string instead of pushing the string in the array like this: `$Skirt_Style[] = 'Pencil';` or `array_push($Skirt_Style, 'Pencil');`

Just replace all your `elseif` statements with an `if` statement to solve this.

Comment: You're absolutely right :-D And once I got it working I discovered that also realized that I needed to remove the foreach statement because it was adding duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

```
$Skirt_Style=array(); // create an array and put it into $Skirt_Style

$Skirt_Style = 'Pencil'; // create a string, and put it into $Skirt_Style
```

Your `Pencil` string will destroy/replace the array you'd created, leaving just the string.

Perhaps you want

```
$Skirt_Style[] = 'Pencil';
            ^^---
```

instead. `[]` is the PHP shortcut notation for "array_push".

Comment: No, the problem is the first if is always true.

Answer (score 1):

You overwritted the array!

This should work:

```
    $Silhouettes = array('Skirt_Style-Pencil','Skirt_Style-Straight','Skirt_Style-A-Line','Skirt_Style-Full','Pant_Style-Straight'); 
    $Skirt_Style=array();
    $Pant_Style=array();

    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Pencil', $Silhouettes))
       $Skirt_Style[] = 'Pencil';

    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Straight', $Silhouettes))
       $Skirt_Style[] = 'Straight';

    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-A-Line', $Silhouettes))
       $Skirt_Style[] = 'A-Line';

    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Full', $Silhouettes))
      $Skirt_Style[] = 'Full';

    if (in_array('Pant_Style-Straight', $Silhouettes))
       $Pant_Style[] = 'Straight';



    var_dump($Skirt_Style);
```

Comment: No. The problem is the first if is always true.

Comment: Now all the if statements are always true and you will fill $Skirt_Style with 20 values...

Answer (score -1):

try this, works for me.

```
$Silhouettes = array('Skirt_Style-Pencil','Skirt_Style-Straight','Skirt_Style-A-Line','Skirt_Style-Full','Pant_Style-Straight'); 
$Skirt_Style=array();
$Pant_Style=array();

for($x = 0; $x < count($Silhouettes);$x++){

    if ($Silhouettes[$x] == 'Skirt_Style-Pencil') {
       $Skirt_Style = 'Pencil';
    }elseif ($Silhouettes[$x] == 'Skirt_Style-Straight') {
       $Skirt_Style = 'Straight';
    }elseif ($Silhouettes[$x] == 'Skirt_Style-A-Line') {
       $Skirt_Style = 'A-Line';
    }elseif ($Silhouettes[$x] == 'Skirt_Style-Full') {
       $Skirt_Style = 'Full';
    }elseif ($Silhouettes[$x] == 'Pant_Style-Straight') {
       $Pant_Style = 'Straight';
    }
    var_dump($Skirt_Style);
}
```

Comment: You are basically checking if value 0 is Skirt_Style-Pencil, etc. Not checking if it exists somewhere in the array. And you don't really need a loop for it the way you've written it. It is basically a loop echoing the Nth known value of a known array, until the last loop when you echo the previous value in the array.

Answer (score -2):

Just get rid of the else statements..
If you're first if gets fired, the else statement is not getting fired....

```
$Silhouettes = array('Skirt_Style-Pencil','Skirt_Style-Straight','Skirt_Style-A-Line','Skirt_Style-Full','Pant_Style-Straight'); 
$Skirt_Style=array();
$Pant_Style=array();

foreach($Silhouettes as $key => $value ){
    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Pencil', $Silhouettes)) {
       $Skirt_Style = 'Pencil';
    }
    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Straight', $Silhouettes)) {
       $Skirt_Style = 'Straight';
    }
    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-A-Line', $Silhouettes)) {
       $Skirt_Style = 'A-Line';
    }
    if (in_array('Skirt_Style-Full', $Silhouettes)) {
       $Skirt_Style = 'Full';
    }
    if (in_array('Pant_Style-Straight', $Silhouettes)) {
       $Pant_Style = 'Straight';
    }
}
var_dump($Skirt_Style);
```

You also need to make Skirt_Style into an array, otherwise it'll just get overwritten by the next if that gets fired.